# How to import third party python module Mac OS X - anki

Tags: python, path, python-module, conda, anki

I am relatively new to programming and posting to Stack Overflow. Please forgive my ignorance.

I am attempting to use a third party module in a program of my own, however I can't work out how to access the module within my Python script.

Mac OS X Sierra 10.12.4
Python 3.6.1
Anaconda 4.3.1

Specifically, I would like to be able to access anki (https://github.com/dae/anki).

I initially tried the line:

```
from anki import Collection
```

That resulted in a 'ModuleNotFoundError'.

Next I tried:

```
conda install anki
```

which also didn't work and yielded a 'PackageNotFoundError'

After more searching, I decided to try:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('usr/share/anki')
from anki import Collection
```

However, this also results in a 'ModuleNotFoundError'

What do I need to do to be able to access this module?

I am sure that it is possible because I have come across several other programs which make use of it:

-https://eshapard.github.io/anki/open-the-anki-database-from-python.html

I recognize that the link above purports to offer a solution to exactly this problem, however the solution proffered isn't working for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because that post assumes a Linux operating system, which has a different directory structure than Mac. You'll need to find out where the equivalent files are stored on macOS, and add that directory instead (sorry, I have no experience with using Anki in Python, so I don't know where the files are). Also, note that there's a difference between `/usr/share/anki` and `usr/share/anki`

Comment: darthbith's comment is correct. The problem here was with the identified path. I solved the problem by changing my path from `usr/share/anki` to `/Users/user/Downloads/anki-master`, where user is the username currently in use. After this correction, the import worked mostly as intended, while failing to import pyaudio. Pyaudio is not useful for my program, so my particular problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are telling about *Anki for desktop computers*, which **IS** application written in Python, but it is **NOT** an *installable Python package*.

So the commands like

```
conda install anki
```

or

```
pip install anki
```

have no meaning.

So the only way is to *download full source code* of this project, *unzip* the content of it (only) folder into *your project* (change you actual folder to it) and then you may do `import` commands.

Comment: MarianD's comment is also helpful and does point down the correct solution path. See my comment above for details.

Comment: Thanx for you notice. In my answer is advice about changing actual folder, too.